# Possible for 2 devs to work on an iOS app w/ APNS enabled?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Me and another dev are working on an iOS app with Apple Push Notification Service. We were working on separate branches of the app and now that I have finished mine with the APNS all working, we were trying to merge and for him to build it into his code. The problem is that the APNS provisioning profile is tied to my account and device, so when he compiles and runs he does not have a valid profile to do the APNS.

Are there any options or workarounds to work on an app with another dev? I can't seem to find anyone else trying to do this so I assume it is either really easy or not possible. We both have individual dev accounts, but I think its crazy if we have to form a company and rebuy team dev accounts just to work on an app together...

Comment: Can't you just send him your certificate?

Comment: the error he gets says he is missing an entitlement for the APNS environment. I am assuming that because I have a provision for MYUNIQUE.com.company.app and his UNIQUE.* have different uniques there is no way for him to get this entitlement. I am not sure what cert you would be referring to?

Comment: You should be using the same app identifier.

Answer (score 0):

you have to be in the same provisioning profile. Both Devices have to be in it too.

If you add a device to a provisioning profile this sometimes doesn't work directly, I have experienced, that you sometimes have to update the provisioning profile again without changeing something.

e.g.:

```
ProvisioningProfile_V1
your DeveloperAcc and your device

updating to ProvisioningProfile_V2
your DeveloperAcc and your device
other dev DeveloperAcc and his device

updating to ProvisioningProfile_V3 //(no changes)
your DeveloperAcc and your device
other dev DeveloperAcc and his device
```

Comment: i can see how to add his device in the provisioning portal, but how would I add his developer account to the profile?

Comment: select his Certificate under modify

Comment: are you in the same developer team?

Comment: So this is what I was thinking might be the source of the problem. We both have single developer accounts because we are not a company so couldnt get a company team developer account. So it wont be possible ??

Comment: ok, I think this is not possible. What you could do: Give him your provisioning profile, export your developerCerts from Keychain and give it to the other dev. then he MAYBE could use it... but I'm not sure. I don't know much about how to build a development team.. our admin did this^^but maybe you both can make a team...

Comment: What you also could do: Use different accounts, he has to build his own appId, provisioningProfile. Then he has to change the AppIdentifier if he works on his account, and you have to use yours. If you want to sen PushMessages you have to change the certificates used to send the Messages to the APNSServer